# Memory Friendly Apply Generator instead of pandas can I read and write same file?

Tags: python, generator, apply

I usually use pandas for this kind of problem. But in this situation I have big troubles with the memory. I would like to avoid to change my computer to manage this trouble.

A possible solution could be use Generator instead of

```
df["column"] = df["column"].apply(func = lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

Can I read and write the same file in the same moment? A possible solution could be read "df.csv" and write "df1.csv" with the new column instead,

What do u think about that?
Am I on track?